# Converting old pagination mysql_query php to PDO

Tags: php, oop, pdo, pagination

I'm trying to switch over to using PDO. I have create a news section on my website.
My database connection is included in my header

I'm currently using this to create the pagination, but need help adding my post
to the `$data = array("Hey","Hello","Good-Bye");` As of now Hey, Hello and Good-Bye are the only items working with the pagination.

Can someone hep me get this result: `$data = array("add my post here")`

**Here is my code:** My database connection is in the header section.

```
<?php
    class Pagination{
        var $data;

        function Paginate($values,$per_page){
            $total_values = count($values);

            if(isset($_GET['page']))
            {
                $current_page = $_GET['page'];

            }
            else
            {
                $current_page = 1;

            }


            $counts = ceil($total_values / $per_page);
            $param1 = ($current_page - 1) * $per_page;
            $this->data = array_slice($values,$param1,$per_page);

            for ($x=1; $x<= $counts; $x++)
            {
                $numbers[] = $x;    
            }

            return $numbers;


        }

        function fetchResult(){
            $resultsValues = $this->data;
            return $resultsValues;

        }
        }



?>
```

**I'm assuming that I need the `<ul class="notices"> - </ul>`(shown below) IN PLACE OF THE `$data = array("Hey","Hello","Good-Bye");` DOWN BELOW
Not sure how to do this though?**

```
    <ul class="notices">

    <?php
    $query = $db->query("SELECT id, date, title, description FROM htp_news");
    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 

    {
    ?>

    <li data-id="id-<?=$row["id"] ?>">
    <article class="box white-bg mb-25">
    <div class="notices-title"><?=$row["title"] ?></div>
    <div class="newsdate" style="margin: 10px 0 !important;"><?= date("F d, Y", strtotime($row["date"])); ?></div>
    <div class="articletext"><style>.articletext img{width:100%; height:auto;}</style><?php $string = $row["description"];
    $max = 300; // or 200, or whatever
    if(strlen($string) > $max) {
      // find the last space < $max:
      $shorter = substr($string, 0, $max+1);
      $string = substr($string, 0, strrpos($shorter, ' ')).'...';
    }
    echo $string;
    ?></div>

    <div class="btn small green white-tx"><a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/htp-news.php?id=<?=$row["id"] ?>">Continue Reading</a></div>

    </article>
    </li>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </ul>



    <div class="grid_8">
<div class="paginationwrap" align="center">
<!--This is where the pagination numbers are being generated-->
<?php
        $pag = new Pagination();
        $data = array("Hey","Hello","Good-Bye");//This is where I'm getting confused..?

        $numbers = $pag->Paginate($data,1);

        $result = $pag->fetchResult();

        foreach($result as $r)
        {
            echo '<div>'.$r.'</div>';   
        }

        foreach($numbers as $num)
        {
            echo'<a href="hydro-transpak-news.php?page='.$num.'">'.$num.'</a>'; 
        }

?>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't quite understand, are you asking for `$data = array("Hey","Hello","Good-Bye", "add my post here");` ?

Comment: @ailvenge I need to know how to add everything inside of the `<ul class="notices">` to the `$data = array` The ul would be in place of Hey Hello Goodbye. "add my post equals" `<ul class="notices">` and list data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why you need it, but to avoid duplication of code and javascript, you could do this like that, and then you have your data inside `$inside_ul` variable.

```
<?php
$query = $db->query("SELECT id, date, title, description FROM htp_news");
$inside_ul = '';
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
    $inside_ul .= '
        <li data-id="id-'.$row["id"].'">
            <article class="box white-bg mb-25">
                <div class="notices-title">'.$row["title"].'</div>
                <div class="newsdate" style="margin: 10px 0 !important;">'.date("F d, Y", strtotime($row["date"])).'</div>
                <div class="articletext"><style>.articletext img{width:100%; height:auto;}</style>
    ';
    $string = $row["description"];
    $max = 300; // or 200, or whatever
    if(strlen($string) > $max) {
        // find the last space < $max:
        $shorter = substr($string, 0, $max+1);
        $string = substr($string, 0, strrpos($shorter, ' ')).'...';
    }
    $inside_ul .= $string.'</div>
                <div class="btn small green white-tx">
                    <a href="http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/htp-news.php?id='.$row["id"].'">Continue Reading</a>
                </div>
            </article>
        </li>
    ';
}
?>
<ul class="notices"><?= $inside_ul; ?></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to do that. Unfortunately I thought thats what I needed to get the pagination to work on the post, but that wasn't it. I'll go ahead and except this as the answer because thats what I asked and that was what I was trying to achieve. Thank You.